# Jenkins SVN checkout borks new files

Tags: svn, corruption, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins CI server which polls an SVN server and checks out the (Maven) project and builds it.

We have recently changed the build server and I set up Jenkins afresh with the few projects we have. Now this new instance has a major problem: Whenever a *new* file has been committed to the SVN repository, the Jenkins `svn update` process will corrupt those *new* files by having their content duplicated. So if one of our developers commits a new file `A` with this content:

```
<test>
</test>
```

then the file will end up in the Jenkins workspace like this:

```
<test>
</test>
<test>
</test>
```

Obviously this is very annoying. I can clear up the situation by wiping the workspace, but really, I don't want to do this every time the build fails. I have never had any troubles with SVN and/or Jenkins before.

What could be the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14551

Comment: That's it, I never noticed that these changes had been coming from a merge. Thanks - and you may want to post this as an answer ;)

Comment: Done. Wasn't too sure about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14551

For the time being, you're best way to handle this is to implement a workaround by the means of automatically clearing out the workspace before building. This may however not the way to go if you have huge and frequent merges - but from my understanding, they're working on it.

Comment: Yes, I've just posted a way to reproduce the bug on the issue tracker, so I hope it'll be fixed some time. We don't merge often, so I'll clean out the workspace by hand when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really trusted Jenkins to be able to handle the workspace changes/updates gracefully, so as a matter of rule, I've always selected the *"Wipe out Workspace"* option, and worked on optimising the SVN server, or the WAN link to the SVN server so that the frequent build/checkout cycles don't destroy the SVN server or the internet connection.